# Angular video not loading after ng-view

Tags: angularjs, video

The videos work fine if I go directly to the page (/stream), but if load that page through ng-view, the video won't load and I'm not sure what's wrong.

In index.html:

```
<a href="#stream">stream</a
<div ng-view></div>
```

In stream.html:

```
<style>
video {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
</style>
<nav class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
        <a href ng-click = "controller.setVideo(0)">
            <div style="text-align:center">stream 1</div>
            <video data-dashjs-player autoplay src="http://localhost:1935/test/test1.stream/manifest.mpd" muted></video>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
        <a href ng-click = "controller.setVideo(1)">
            <div style="text-align:center">stream 2</div>
            <video data-dashjs-player autoplay src="http://vm2.dashif.org/livesim/testpic_2s/Manifest.mpd" muted></video>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

In app.js:

```
App.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "main.html"
        })
        .when("/stream", {
            templateUrl : "stream.html"
        });
});
```